# Library problem with Dbeaver: No native library found error

Tags: fedora, dbeaver

when i want to connect my sqlite database on dbeaver i receive the following error:
No native library found for os.name=Linux, os.arch=x86_64, paths=[/org/sqlite/native/Linux/x86_64:/usr/java/packages/lib:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib]

Drivers where succesfully downloaded and installed from maven.org

When i check my libfiles for sqlite i find the following path: /usr/lib64/libsqlite3.so.0
How can this error be if the lib file is available in the path that the program looks for?